# How to close javascript dropdown menu by clicking anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a javascript dropdown menu. I got it from some site it works fine but problem is the dropdown menu closes only when menu button is clicked. How can I make dropdown menu close even when I click any where else on page.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">ddm</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding a FIDDLE.

Comment: The normal select box in HTML will disappear if you click on any other place in the screen

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, it should work

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#myDropdown').length) {
        if($('#myDropdown').is(":visible")) {
            $('#myDropdown').hide()
        }
    }        
})
```

Comment: Confirmed this works for me in Edge.  I've also messaged W3Schools to point out the issue in their dropdown example, which is where you might have got the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:-

```
var dropdown = $('dropdown_selector');
$(document).click(function(e){
if(e.target === dropdown.get(0))
    {
        // hide dropdawn code here
    }
});
```

Comment: You can find the demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/VrmnA/7/

Answer (score 0):

**onBlur** event is triggered when an element loses focus.

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").onblur = function() {
    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: but it does not have focus...

Comment: This might apply when you have a drop-down triggered by a hover, but in other cases you open through a click, which is a better design for touch devices.  In that case `blur` doesn't apply.