# event.target.matches doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error in IE:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'matches'".

Tried to close the dropdown list when clicking outside.

Below is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Options</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#directory" class="directory">Content Directory</a>
    <a href="#objective" class="objective">Objectives</a>
    <a href="#reference" class="reference">Reference</a>
    <a href="#help" class="help">Help</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34994338/746984

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#myDropdown').length) {
        if($('#myDropdown').is(":visible")) {
            $('#myDropdown').hide();
        }
    }        
});
```

Worked for me.  I've also messaged w3schools, who provided the original example that has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good 15 minutes trying to figure it out.

Use the same code but change `.matches` to `.contains` and get rid of that exclamation point.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target.contains(".dropbtn")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
};
```

This should fix all your problems without all the confusion.

Comment: This will result in `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`